Debugging issue with Flutter and Android Studio
I have Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1.
A completely new Flutter application, the default one, with no changes at all.
The debugging appears as below.
There is this pink color to the white area of the editor
As you see at the top, the main.dart file is opened twice (by Android Studio)
Breakpoint don't appear and the app stops where the breakpoint was in the normal main.dart
9 errors appears on the right and in the panel below.
Aside from that, the application executes correctly.
I execute "invalidate caches". I emptied the cache directory.
This behavior appears the last week in every application that I have (in 2 different PCs)
What's wrong?? How can I fix this?


Can you try reinstalling the flutter plugin on android studio

@Md.YeasinSheikh I could but I experience this behavior in 2 different PCs! You mean that the Flutter plugin is corrupted in 2 different PC's at the same time!!

well I kinda doubt it. let's try with cache repair, dart pub cache repair

@Md.YeasinSheikh I tried the cache repair but the problem persist. By the way, I'm able to run and debug all my projects with VS Code without any issues

humz, you can try uninstall the android-studio, clean the studio tempFile+cache, restart the PC(;, and install the android-studio again.

@Md.YeasinSheikh You think that in both PCs there is something wrong with Android Studio??...isn't a bit far fetched that Android Studio has the same problem in 2 different computers??

well if we follow the same approach on both one, result will be the same.  once I gets any trouble I rollback to a state and start following the doc.

@Md.YeasinSheikh Have you seen that problem before or you just guessing?

reinstalling the flutter plugin and then restarting the IDE worked for me and rest are guess which may or maynot work but it worked for many I have said theses.
